# Вызов функции из функции / Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите найти решение.

При вызове функции *send_message*, она должна вызывать функцию *check_status*.

Функция *check_status* проверяет значение переменной *status*,
если значение 1, то функция *send_message* должна продолжить работать,
а если *status == 0*, то функция send_message должна остановиться.

Выполнить проверку *stasus* внутри функции я не могу, потому что будет еще не сколько функций, где нужно будет проверять *status*. Я не хочу нарушать принцип пайтона DRY

```
status = 0


def stop(message):
    global status
    if message == '/stop':
        status = 0
    else:
        None


def check_status():
    global status
    if status == 1:
        return
    else:
        None


def send_message(message):
    check_status()
    print('qq')


print(status)
send_message('Privet')
print(status)
```

Вот какой ответ мне возвращает терминал:

```
(venv) fastlinkdevops@DevOps:~/dev/bot/Drinking_Companion_BOT$ python3 test.py
0
qq
0
```

**Я хочу избежать такой конструкции, в пользу вызовов функций, в которых будут проходить проверки**

```
def send_message(message):
    if check_status():
        if user_id in black_list:
            if user_id in group_user:
                print('hi')
            else:
                None
        else:
            print('Вы в чс')
    else:
        None
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: Что именно не понятно? Есть глобальная переменная status, если значение 1, то должна выполняться функция send_message, если значение status 0, то функция send_message не должна работать

Comment: Ну проверяй свою глобальную переменную. Если 1,то выполняй, если 0, то не выполняй. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с Exception:

```
status = 0

def check_status(status: int):
    if status == 0:
        raise Exception("Status is bad")
    
def send_message(message):
    global status
    try:
        check_status(status)
    except:
        return
    print('qq')
    
print(status)
send_message('Privet')
print(status)
```

Вывод:

```
0
0
```

т.к. status = 0

По аналогии добавляем другие функции проверки

Comment: Спасибо, все работает так, как мне и нужно :)

Comment: Отдавайте голос за ответ:) Стрелка вверх:) А лучше как правильный ответ:)

Comment: Непонятно - чем же это лучше `if`? Вместо одной понятной проверки `if check_status:` много дополнительных строк нужно писать.

Comment: Требование заказчика :) Про "лучше" никто не говорил :)

Comment: @Виктор Ну, если требование "избавиться от `if` любой ценой" - тогда понятно. А если сделать просто и удобно, то это не так )

Comment: @CrazyElf Всякое бывает:)

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_status():
    global status
    if status == 0:
       return False
    if user_id in black_list:
       return False
    if not (user_id in group_user):
       return False
    return True
           

def send_message(message):
    if check_status():
        print('qq')
```

Можно проверить много условий

Глобальная переменная зло, выстрелит в не подходящий момент.

Comment: Данный способ мне не совсем подходит. Я хочу отказаться от if в фукнции send_message.. Мне по мимо статуса нужна будет проверять еще black list, список с юзерами в черном списке. Уже получается будет if в if. (Проверяться статус if status == 1, потом проверяться еще if user_id in black_list

Comment: Что мешает проверить черный список? `Есть глобальная переменная status, если значение 1, то должна выполняться функция send_message, если значение status 0, то функция send_message не должна работать` - все в соответствии с тех. заданием.

Comment: после проверки статуса должна быть проверка на наличие юзера в черном списке. Соответственно у меня будет проверка внутри блока проверки статуса..А если мне нужно будет проверить еще условие, это будет еще одна проверка но уже внутри блока проверки черного списка и так далее? Я именно по этой причине и хочу, чтобы все проверки if  выполнялись в других функциях

Comment: Все верно текущая проверка происходит в check_status() и по результату проверки происходит действие print('qq').

Comment: А мне нужно немного другое. Чтоб функция send_message вызывала функцию check_status, если проверка не пройдена, то функция send_message  останавливается, также и с последующими проверками. Я добавил пример кода, который я хочу избежать, можешь взглянуть? :)

Comment: Используйте исключения для такого случая и конструкцию try ...

Comment: Можете написать ваше решение с помощью исключения? Я пробовал, но у меня все равно после проверки работает функция send_message

Comment: Можно добавить множество условий см ответ

Comment: Спасибо, ваш способ рабочий и подходит мне :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать **декоратор**.

**Код:**

```py
status = 0

def check_status(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if status == 0:
            return
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@check_status
def send_message(message):
    print(message)

status = 1
print(status)
send_message('Privet')

status = 0
print(status)
send_message('Poka')
```

**Вывод:**

```
1
Privet
0
```

Как видно по выводу программы, при статусе выставленном в 1 задекорированная функция отработала, а при статусе 0 - нет.

Декораторы - очень удобный инструмент для управления поведением функций без изменения их кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за код. Я знал, что декоратор будет самое правильное решение, но т.к. я еще только учусь, не смог самостоятельно его использовать.